# The part after the # symbol does not get called in the Gatling simulation

Tags: scala, gatling

The part after the # symbol does not get called in the Gatling simulation.

```
 http("userManagementUserRoleEdit")
      .get("/client/#/admin/edit_user_role/2")
      .check(status.is(200))
      .check(substring("Edit User Role"))
```

The URL that I wish to call - "https://orangehrm-demo-6x.orangehrmlive.com/client/#/admin/edit_user_role/38"

The URL that gets called - "https://orangehrm-demo-6x.orangehrmlive.com/client/"

What can be done here in order to get the page which I really need to hit?

Comment: Everything after hash is up for client, not server, to handle. It's likely the thing you're testing loads some JS and then renders different pages based on that segment, so you'll need a full browser to test it.

Comment: @Oleg Pyzhcov Agree with the part of your comment about the fragment. However, you don't need a full browser to test, you need to figure out the server calls are actually made.

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE well, you're right. Tho if the "Edit User Role" substring only appears from JS rendering, you won't be able to check for it like this. But for load-testing, the author should be replicating whatever browser is requesting, not whatever it's rendering.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov While inspecting I can only find xhr URLs of this type - https://orangehrm-demo-6x.orangehrmlive.com/api/something,
That, when called from Gatling, would give me a 401 error and when just browsed gave me "[ ]" on the page.